# C# Formatting Age - Regarding Days, Weeks , Months - Years

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, formatting

I am working on some medical software and I am required to output all ages in a very specific manner, based on the following rules:

```
 If under 6 Weeks old :  ###D (Number of Days)
If under 6 Months old :  ###W (Number of Weeks)
 If under 2 Years old :  ###M (Number of Months)
 If above 2 Years old :  ###Y (Number of Years)
```

Using C# I am trying to find a simple method of doing this just using a Person's Date of Birth, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was working on something similar yesterday, but something like this should suit your needs: (*assuming 7 day weeks, 31 day months, 365 day years etc.*)

**Revised Method :** *(Fixed as per Bob's suggestions)*

```
public static string ConvertAge(DateTime dob)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        string fmt = "{0:0##}{1}";

        //Greater than 2 Years old - Ouput Years
        if (dob <= today.AddYears(-2)) 
            return string.Format(fmt, (dob.DayOfYear <= today.DayOfYear) ? 
            (today.Year - dob.Year) : (today.Year - dob.Year)-1, "Y");
        //Less than 2 Years - Output Months
        if (dob < today.AddMonths(-2)) 
            return string.Format(fmt, (dob.DayOfYear <= today.DayOfYear) ? 
            (today.Year - dob.Year) * 12 + (today.Month - dob.Month) : 
            ((today.Year - dob.Year) * 12 + (today.Month - dob.Month))-1 , "M");
        //Less than 2 Months - Output Weeks
        if (dob < today.AddDays(-2 * 7)) 
            return string.Format(fmt, (today - dob).Days / 7, "W");
        //Less than 2 Weeks - Output Days
        return string.Format(fmt, (today - dob).Days, "D");
    }
```

**Previous Method :**

```
public string ConvertAge(DateTime dateOfBirth)
        {
            int daysOld = (DateTime.Now - dateOfBirth).Days;

            //Age < 6 Weeks
            if (daysOld < (6 * 7)) 
                return String.Format("{0:0##}{1}", daysOld, 'D'); 
            //Age < 6 Months
            else if (daysOld < (6 * 31)) 
                return String.Format("{0:0##}{1}", daysOld/7, 'W');
            //Age < 2 Years
            else if (daysOld < (2 * 365)) 
                return String.Format("{0:0##}{1}", daysOld / 31, 'M');
            //Age >= 2 Years
            else 
                return String.Format("{0:0##}{1}", daysOld / 365, 'Y');
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: For the years old calculation use .Years instead of .Days..... should make the calculations proper accounting for leap years.

Comment: +1 It would be elegant to implement your solution as an extension method.

Comment: @Andrew Good Point :), @Felice - in my original implementation it was an an extension method, just modified it for OP's needs.

Comment: Isn't the only difference between TotalDays and Days that TotalDays stores a double (including fractional days) - do you think this would make much of a difference in this implementation?

Comment: Thanks everyone - I tried this out and it seems to be doing exactly what I needed it to :)

Comment: I suspect the assumption of 31 days per month (not to mention the assumption of 365 days per year) would make this method not work correctly, because the actual length (in days) of a 6-month period depends entirely on *which* 6 months you're talking about. The correct way would be to take the birth date and add 6 to the month value (wrapping back around and incremented the year by one if after June 30th), and then using this as a reference date to determine whether the person is 6 months old or not.

Answer (score 3):

A DateTime type can be subtracted from other DateTimes, resulting in a TimeSpan representing the gap. Try this:

```
var timeAlive = DateTime.Today - dateOfBirth.Date;
```

Then, look at the Days, Months and Years (divide Days by 7 for Weeks) of timeAlive, and format accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The following makes no assumptions about days/months or year.
On the downside, it is not Y3K compatible.

```
    public static string GetAge (DateTime dob) {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        string fmt = "{0:0##}{1}";

        if (dob < today.AddYears(-2)) return string.Format(fmt, today.Year - dob.Year, "Y");
        if (dob < today.AddMonths(-6))return string.Format(fmt, (today.Year - dob.Year)*12 + (today.Month - dob.Month), "M");
        if (dob < today.AddDays(-6 * 7)) return string.Format(fmt, (today - dob).Days/7, "W");
        return string.Format(fmt, (today - dob).Days, "D");
    }
```

Comment: +1 This is the only one with code that precisely meets the specs.  Out of curiosity, why isn't it Y3K compatible?

Comment: It would be. I frequently use 2 digit years and often write things that will not survive the century.  That doesn't apply here.

Comment: +1 Nice function Bob! (very concise) - however I don't believe that it takes into consideration if the person's birthday has passed already this year. I input my own birthday to find that I was a year older than I actually am.

Comment: If you change the Age line to the following it will take care of the above problem: if (dob < today.AddYears(-2)) return string.Format(fmt, (dob.DayOfYear <= today.DayOfYear) ? (today.Year - dob.Year) : (today.Year - dob.Year)-1, "Y");

Comment: You're right.  I was focused on the issue of the variable days/month and year; I've bumped into that problems many times.  I should have commented that it was an untested function and doomed to have a bug!  Good Catch!

Answer (score 0):

You can get an object representing the user's current age with a simple subtraction:

```
TimeSpan age = DateTime.Now - dateOfBirth;
```

And then it's just a matter of doing a bunch of if clauses

```
if (age.TotalDays < 6 * 7) // 6 weeks
    // ...
else if (age.TotalDays < 6 * 30) // 6 months
    // ...
// et cetera
```

You should be able to figure out how to do your formatting.