# DateTime difference returing correct no of months and or even years?

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there any built-in function how can I get the difference between tho DateTime objects in better way than just number of days? I mean something like 1 month, 23 days. I find it pretty hard to calculate due to differnet number of days in each month, leap years etc.
Thanks

Comment: This is meaningless unless you can state _what_ you want exactly. How long is a Month? Many business  sections have their own rules.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com). It's not production-ready in general yet, but the relevant bits may work well enough for your current requirements :)

Note that `TimeSpan` will *not* do what you want, because "1 month" can mean a different number of days depending on the month, and a `TimeSpan` isn't anchored.

In Noda Time, you want a `Period`. For example:

```
LocalDate start = new LocalDate(2010, 4, 15);
LocalDate end = new LocalDate(2010, 6, 19);
Period period = Period.Between(start, end); // Defaults to Year/Month/Day

Console.WriteLine(period.Months); // 2
Console.WriteLine(period.Days); // 4
```

Note that [date/time arithmetic is hard](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic.aspx)... in some cases "the right answer" isn't at all obvious.

Comment: Behind the scenes, any insight into how its calculating Months/Days?

Comment: @Nix: With a lot of work :) It's mostly pinched from Joda Time, and the calendar system calculations are pretty hairy. Feel free to download the whole source and step through it though...

Comment: I just perused through the code, and its just subtracting each field (day,month, etc).  So I don't understand what Noda would buy you?

Comment: @Nix: It's subtracting it *in a calendar-sensitive way*. Really drill down into the code and you'll see it's doing a lot of work. Try a slightly tougher example than the one I gave - instead of going to June 19th, go to June 14th, so that it's 1 month and 30 days...

Comment: needless to say you are right, deep in the code Field code there is logic that handles the cases with varying month days.

Answer (score 3):

Simple subtraction will do the job:

```
int months = departure.Months - arrival.Months;
int years = departure.Years - arrival.Years;
//in case multiple years have elapsed .
int months += years * 12;
```

You obviously would need to do some math when it comes to days, if you dont care about precision if the day difference is negative you will need to subtract one from the month.

---

And then you could use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) To get more precision aka elapsed time.

```
//Microsoft Documentation Example:

DateTime departure = new DateTime(2010, 6, 12, 18, 32, 0);
DateTime arrival = new DateTime(2010, 6, 13, 22, 47, 0);
TimeSpan travelTime = arrival - departure;  
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", arrival, departure, travelTime);   

// The example displays the following output:
//       6/13/2010 10:47:00 PM - 6/12/2010 6:32:00 PM = 1.04:15:00
```

Comment: From what I recall, TimeSpan knows nothing about the start and end date - only the difference between them, so you wouldn't be able to do something like 'How many months between these two dates'

Comment: Yes, I am using Date1-Date2 but in the properties, there are just Days

Comment: Also make sure to use the .TotalDays and .TotalHours properties instead of .Hours and .Days...   This is a common gotcha.

Comment: To include a number of months you need more than TimeSpan, precisely because a month isn't a fixed number of days.

Answer (score 3):

Months can consist of 28, 29, 30, or 31 days; years can be 365 or 366 days. Therefore, problems arise when you try to calculate full units of time for months and years, So if you can assume something then you can check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901866/c-formatting-age-regarding-days-weeks-months-years)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is surprisingly hard to specify for calendar dates.  Take a look here for a good calculation of how to compute a person's age in years.

[Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

The complexity comes from the edge cases.  Obviously Jan 31st is a month after Dec 31st.  But, is Feb 28th a month after Jan 31st?  In a normal year? In a leap year?  Before you can code this you need to specify these kinds of cases.

The birthday algorithm uses a round-down and increment strategy.  That will work for month differences as well, given your answer to the question in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I just wrote to calculate the difference in years, months, and days.  It is in the public domain.

```
    public sealed class DateDifference {
            int years;

            public int Years {
                get { return years; }
            }
            int months;

            public int Months {
                get { return months; }
            }
            int days;

            public int Days {
                get { return days; }
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("[DateDifference Years={0}, Months={1}, Days={2}]", years, months, days);
            }


            public DateDifference(DateTime earlier, DateTime later){
                if(later<earlier)
                    throw new ArgumentException("later is earlier than 'earlier'.");
                bool isleapday=(earlier.Month==2 && earlier.Day==29);
                DateTime tmp=isleapday ? new DateTime(earlier.Year,2,28) : earlier;
                while(true){
                    try {
                        tmp=tmp.AddYears(1);
                        if(isleapday && DateTime.IsLeapYear(tmp.Year))
                            tmp=new DateTime(tmp.Year,2,29);
                    } catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException){
                        break;
                    }
                    if(tmp<=later){
                        years++;
                        earlier=tmp;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Add months
                tmp=earlier;
                while(true){
                    try {
                        tmp=tmp.AddMonths(1);
                    if(isleapday && tmp.Day!=29 && tmp.Month!=2)
                        tmp=new DateTime(tmp.Year,tmp.Month,29);
                    } catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException){
                        break;
                    }
                    if(tmp<=later){
                        months++;
                        earlier=tmp;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                tmp=earlier;
                while(true){
                    try {
                        tmp=tmp.AddDays(1);
                    } catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException){
                        break;
                    }
                    if(tmp<=later){
                        days++;
                        earlier=tmp;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Example:

```
var dd=new DateDifference(new DateTime(2010,6,29),new DateTime(2012,2,29));
Console.WriteLine(dd.Years); // displays 1
Console.WriteLine(dd.Months); // displays 8
Console.WriteLine(dd.Days); // displays 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **DateDiff** class of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void DateDiffSample()
{
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime( 2009, 11, 8, 7, 13, 59 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date1: {0}", date1 );
  // > Date1: 08.11.2009 07:13:59
  DateTime date2 = new DateTime( 2011, 3, 20, 19, 55, 28 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date2: {0}", date2 );
  // > Date2: 20.03.2011 19:55:28

  DateDiff dateDiff = new DateDiff( date1, date2 );

  // differences
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Years: {0}", dateDiff.Years );
  // > DateDiff.Years: 1
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Quarters: {0}", dateDiff.Quarters );
  // > DateDiff.Quarters: 5
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Months: {0}", dateDiff.Months );
  // > DateDiff.Months: 16
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Weeks: {0}", dateDiff.Weeks );
  // > DateDiff.Weeks: 70
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Days: {0}", dateDiff.Days );
  // > DateDiff.Days: 497
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Weekdays: {0}", dateDiff.Weekdays );
  // > DateDiff.Weekdays: 71
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Hours: {0}", dateDiff.Hours );
  // > DateDiff.Hours: 11940
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Minutes: {0}", dateDiff.Minutes );
  // > DateDiff.Minutes: 716441
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.Seconds: {0}", dateDiff.Seconds );
  // > DateDiff.Seconds: 42986489

  // elapsed
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedYears: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedYears );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedYears: 1
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedMonths: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedMonths );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedMonths: 4
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedDays: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedDays );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedDays: 12
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedHours: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedHours );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedHours: 12
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedMinutes: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedMinutes );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedMinutes: 41
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedSeconds: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedSeconds );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedSeconds: 29
} // DateDiffSample
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    public string YearsMonthsDaysDiff(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
    {
        Int32 mD = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateTo.Year, dateTo.AddMonths(-1).Month); //first check out days in month before dateTo month
        Int32 D1 = dateFrom.Day;
        Int32 M1 = dateFrom.Month;
        Int32 Y1 = dateFrom.Year;
        Int32 D2 = dateTo.Day;
        Int32 M2 = dateTo.Month;
        Int32 Y2 = dateTo.Year;

        // Substract each datetime components accordingly
        D2 -= D1;
        M2 -= M1;
        Y2 -= Y1;
        if (D2 < 0)
        {
            D2 += mD;// D2 is less then D1, then add mD
            M2 -= 1; // but, substract 1 from M2 
        }
        if (M2 < 0)
        {
            M2 += 12; // if M2 is less then M1, then add with 12
            Y2 -= 1; // but substract 1 from Y2 
        }
        return Y2.ToString("## years ") + M2.ToString("##  months ") + D2.ToString("## days");
    }
```

it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that allows you to query various properties of the difference of a pair of DateTimes. I just whipped it up now, and am releasing it into the public domain. Do with it as you will, but use it at your own risk.

```
public static class DateCalcs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer number of years between start and finish
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">Start DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="finish">FinishDateTime</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int YearDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        DateTime _start, _finish;
        bool _negate = (finish < start);
        if(_negate)
        {
            _start = finish;
            _finish = start;
        }
        else
        {
            _start = start;
            _finish = finish;
        }
        int _diff = 0;
        while(_start.AddYears(1) < _finish)
        {
            _diff++;
            _start = _start.AddYears(1);
        }

        if(_negate)
        {
            _diff = _diff * (-1);
        }

        return _diff;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer number of months between start and finish
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">Start DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="finish">Finish DateTime</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int MonthDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        DateTime _start, _finish;
        bool _negate = (finish < start);
        if (_negate)
        {
            _start = finish;
            _finish = start;
        }
        else
        {
            _start = start;
            _finish = finish;
        }
        int _diff = 0;
        while (_start.AddMonths(1) < _finish)
        {
            _diff++;
            _start = _start.AddMonths(1);
        }

        if (_negate)
        {
            _diff = _diff * (-1);
        }

        return _diff;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer number of days between start and finish
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">start DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="finish">finish DateTime</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int DayDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {

        var _diff = finish - start;
        return (int)_diff.TotalDays;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer number of hours between start and finish
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">start DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="finish">finish DateTime</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int HourDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        var _diff = finish - start;
        return(int)_diff.TotalHours;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer number of minutes between start and finish
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">start DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="finish">finish DateTime</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int MinuteDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        var _diff = finish - start;
        return (int)_diff.TotalMinutes;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer number of seconds between start and finish
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">start DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="finish">finish DateTime</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int SecondDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        var _diff = finish - start;
        return (int)_diff.TotalSeconds;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer number of milliseconds between start and finish
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">start DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="finish">finish DateTime</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int MilliSecondDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        var _diff = finish - start;
        return (int)_diff.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer remaining number of months between two DateTimes 
    /// after the year difference has been removed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">start DateTime</param>
    /// <param name="finish">finish DateTime</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int MonthPartDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        return MonthDiff(start.AddYears(YearDiff(start, finish)), finish);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer remaining number of days between two DateTimes 
    /// after the year difference and the month difference has been removed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start"></param>
    /// <param name="finish"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int DayPartDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        return DayDiff(start.AddMonths(MonthDiff(start, finish)), finish);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer remaining number of hours between two DateTimes 
    /// after the year, month and day difference has been removed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start"></param>
    /// <param name="finish"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int HourPartDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        return (finish-start).Hours;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer remaining number of minutes between two DateTimes 
    /// after the year, month, day and hour difference has been removed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start"></param>
    /// <param name="finish"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int MinutePartDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        return (finish-start).Minutes;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer remaining number of seconds between two DateTimes 
    /// after the year, month, day, hour and minute difference has been removed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start"></param>
    /// <param name="finish"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int SecondPartDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        return (finish - start).Seconds;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the integer remaining number of milliseconds between two DateTimes 
    /// after the year, month, day, hour, minute and second difference has been removed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start"></param>
    /// <param name="finish"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int MilliSecondPartDiff(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
    {
        return (finish - start).Milliseconds;
    }

}
```

So you could call it like this:

```
var finish = DateTime.Now;
var start = new DateTime(1967, 7, 3);

var years = DateCalcs.YearDiff(start, finish);
Console.WriteLine ("Age in years: {0}", years);
var months = DateCalcs.MonthDiff(start, finish);
Console.WriteLine("Age in months: {0}", months);
var days = DateCalcs.DayDiff(start, finish);
Console.WriteLine("Age in days: {0}", days);
var hours = DateCalcs.HourDiff(start, finish);
Console.WriteLine("Age in hours: {0}", hours);
var minutes = DateCalcs.MinuteDiff(start, finish);
Console.WriteLine("Age in minutes: {0}", minutes);
var seconds = DateCalcs.SecondDiff(start, finish);
Console.WriteLine("Age in seconds: {0}", seconds);
var milliSeconds = DateCalcs.MilliSecondDiff(start, finish);
Console.WriteLine("Age in milliseconds: {0}", milliSeconds);

var AgeString = string.Format("{0}yr, {1}mo, {2}d, {3}h, {4}m, {5}s, {6}ms",
    DateCalcs.YearDiff(start, finish),
    DateCalcs.MonthPartDiff(start, finish),
    DateCalcs.DayPartDiff(start, finish),
    DateCalcs.HourPartDiff(start, finish),
    DateCalcs.MinutePartDiff(start, finish),
    DateCalcs.SecondPartDiff(start, finish),
    DateCalcs.MilliSecondPartDiff(start, finish)
    );

Console.WriteLine("Or {0}", AgeString);
```

Which just now returned

```
Age in years: 46
Age in months: 560
Age in days: 17073
Age in hours: 409771
Age in minutes: 24586290
Age in seconds: 1475177401
Age in milliseconds: -2147483648
Or 46yr, 8mo, 28d, 19h, 30m, 1s, 792ms
```