# Problems formatting dates

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

Here is the set up, I have a JSON feed I am using and I want to find the difference between two specific dates called `posted_date` and `planned_expiration_date`. They are in an odd format I so I thought I could truncate them down to just the date.I could then use `NSTimeInterval` to find the difference in seconds.

```
// Time Interval Left
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSString *startDate = [firstPerson objectForKey:@"posted_date"];
NSString *endDate = [firstPerson objectForKey:@"planned_expiration_date"];

//Ammend the strings to YYYY-MM-DD
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
int newlength = 9;
NSDate *startDateAmmended =[formatter dateFromString:[startDate substringFromIndex:newlength]];
NSDate *endDateAmmended = [formatter dateFromString:[endDate substringFromIndex:newlength]];
```

Here is the bit I'm not too sure about. The date appears something like this `"2013-06-07T13:40:01Z"` straight from the feed. I don't know how to deal with the T and Z chars in the date formatter method so I truncate the string with `substringFromIndex` to make it 10 chars and then attempted the following code.

```
//Difference in Date
NSTimeInterval *startDifference = [startDateAmmended timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSTimeInterval *endDifference = [endDateAmmended timeIntervalSinceNow];

NSTimeInterval timeDifferenceInSeconds = startDifference - endDifference;
```

I get the following error, `.../JSONParser/ViewController.m:52:21: Initializing 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *') with an expression of incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')` at the first two calls to `NSTimeInterval`.

I am sure I'm going wrong in a few places and I'm sure this isn't the easiest method of doing it. Could anyone recommend how I would fix this issue or an easier way to go about getting the differences between dates?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742771/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates-without-using-any-ready-library-fu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from your lines that say:

```
NSTimeInterval *startDifference = [startDateAmmended timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSTimeInterval *endDifference = [endDateAmmended timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

They should be:

```
NSTimeInterval startDifference = [startDateAmmended timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSTimeInterval endDifference = [endDateAmmended timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

Or, more simply, don't define those two difference variables at all, and just use:

```
NSTimeInterval timeDifferenceInSeconds = [endDateAmmended timeIntervalSinceDate:startDateAmmended];
```

---

To calculate the difference between two [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) / [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) date strings, you can do:

```
NSDate *startDate = [self dateFromISO8601String:@"2013-06-01T16:27:35Z"];
NSDate *endDate   = [self dateFromISO8601String:@"2013-06-07T13:40:01Z"];

NSTimeInterval elapsed = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSLog(@"Time elapsed (in seconds) is %.0f", elapsed);
```

where `dateFromISO8601String` is defined as:

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromISO8601String:(NSString *)string
{
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil)
    {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
        formatter.locale = enUSPOSIXLocale;
        formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";
        formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    }
    return [formatter dateFromString:string];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the difference in seconds between two `NSDate` objects like this:

```
double difference = [startDateAmmended timeIntervalSinceDate:endDateAmmended];
```

Note that with the substring operation you don't have the time, only the date, so the `difference` will be in seconds but with steps of whole days.